# jsf 2.0 servlet 3.0 based app - war file gives run time exception in production server

Tags: tomcat, jsf, servlets

Need some help in a matter related to JSF2.0 and Servlet 3.0 based war file deployment in production server. I am using jsf based java prime faces framework which provides me a built in ui required for this project.

I had procured an ubuntu server for the development & QA phase (AWS). I used to install Apache tomcat 8.0 in it and test our War file. All worked fine and is currently working fine also.

we tried in another weblogic server installed on windows machine, it just worked fine.

The customer provided us a production server (initially redhat linux) it threw the error (screen shot attached). We requested for a ubuntu server, that is also showing the same error. These machines are all on premise and i have installed same tomcat 8 on them
The error i get is

```
Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet faces Servlet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)...

Root cause

java.lang.illegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:555)...
```

Request some troubleshooting ideas to resolve this. The tomcat server log file looks like this.

```
  org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CollectionQuerySpaceImpl@10acd8fe]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:3> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@2eac749c]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : updatedDate
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG FetchStyleLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy:150 - Building LoadPlan...
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor:101 - processing queryspace <gen:0>
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG LoadPlanTreePrinter:55 - LoadPlan(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Item.categories)
    - Returns
       - CollectionReturnImpl(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Item.categories, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Item.categories])
          - (collection element) CollectionFetchableElementEntityGraph(entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Category, querySpaceUid=<gen:1>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Item.categories].<elements>)
             - CollectionAttributeFetchImpl(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Category.subCategories, querySpaceUid=<gen:2>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Item.categories].<elements>.subCategories)
                - (collection element) CollectionFetchableElementEntityGraph(entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.SubCategory, querySpaceUid=<gen:3>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Item.categories].<elements>.subCategories.<elements>)
    - QuerySpaces
       - CollectionQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Item.categories)
          - SQL table alias mapping - categories0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {itemId4_0_0_}
          - entity-element alias suffix - 1_
          - 1_entity-element suffixed key columns - id1_0_1_
          - JOIN (JoinDefinedByMetadata(elements)) : <gen:0> -> <gen:1>
             - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:1>, entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Category)
                - SQL table alias mapping - categories0_
                - alias suffix - 1_
                - suffixed key columns - {id1_0_1_}

2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG CollectionLoader:83 - Static select for collection com.aaa.bbb.domain.Item.categories: select categories0_.itemId as itemId4_0_0_, categories0_.id as id1_0_0_, categories0_.id as id1_0_1_, categories0_.categoryName as category2_0_1_, categories0_.isActive as isActive3_0_1_, categories0_.itemId as itemId4_0_1_, categories0_.updatedDate as updatedD5_0_1_, (select i.name from item i where i.id = categories0_.itemId) as formula0_1_ from categories categories0_ where categories0_.itemId=? order by categories0_.id
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:0> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CollectionQuerySpaceImpl@51282c29]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:1> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@7cf4879b]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : cities
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:2> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CollectionQuerySpaceImpl@57f5633e]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:3> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@f65ee04]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : isActive
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : name
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : regionId
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : regionName
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : updatedDate
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG FetchStyleLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy:150 - Building LoadPlan...
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor:101 - processing queryspace <gen:0>
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG LoadPlanTreePrinter:55 - LoadPlan(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Region.states)
    - Returns
       - CollectionReturnImpl(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Region.states, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Region.states])
          - (collection element) CollectionFetchableElementEntityGraph(entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.State, querySpaceUid=<gen:1>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Region.states].<elements>)
             - CollectionAttributeFetchImpl(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.State.cities, querySpaceUid=<gen:2>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Region.states].<elements>.cities)
                - (collection element) CollectionFetchableElementEntityGraph(entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.City, querySpaceUid=<gen:3>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Region.states].<elements>.cities.<elements>)
    - QuerySpaces
       - CollectionQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Region.states)
          - SQL table alias mapping - states0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {regionId4_10_0_}
          - entity-element alias suffix - 1_
          - 1_entity-element suffixed key columns - id1_10_1_
          - JOIN (JoinDefinedByMetadata(elements)) : <gen:0> -> <gen:1>
             - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:1>, entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.State)
                - SQL table alias mapping - states0_
                - alias suffix - 1_
                - suffixed key columns - {id1_10_1_}

2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG CollectionLoader:83 - Static select for collection com.aaa.bbb.domain.Region.states: select states0_.regionId as regionId4_10_0_, states0_.id as id1_10_0_, states0_.id as id1_10_1_, states0_.isActive as isActive2_10_1_, states0_.name as name3_10_1_, states0_.regionId as regionId4_10_1_, states0_.updatedDate as updatedD5_10_1_, (select r.name from region r where r.id = states0_.regionId) as formula3_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.regionId=?
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:0> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CollectionQuerySpaceImpl@4b960b78]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:1> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@6eabfc6a]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : orderId
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : price
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : productId
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : quantity
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : _orderDetails_orderIdBackref
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG FetchStyleLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy:150 - Building LoadPlan...
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor:101 - processing queryspace <gen:0>
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG LoadPlanTreePrinter:55 - LoadPlan(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Order.orderDetails)
    - Returns
       - CollectionReturnImpl(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Order.orderDetails, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Order.orderDetails])
          - (collection element) CollectionFetchableElementEntityGraph(entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.OrderMapping, querySpaceUid=<gen:1>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.Order.orderDetails].<elements>)
    - QuerySpaces
       - CollectionQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.Order.orderDetails)
          - SQL table alias mapping - orderdetai0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {orderId2_4_0_}
          - entity-element alias suffix - 1_
          - 1_entity-element suffixed key columns - id1_4_1_
          - JOIN (JoinDefinedByMetadata(elements)) : <gen:0> -> <gen:1>
             - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:1>, entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.OrderMapping)
                - SQL table alias mapping - orderdetai0_
                - alias suffix - 1_
                - suffixed key columns - {id1_4_1_}

2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG CollectionLoader:83 - Static select for collection com.aaa.bbb.domain.Order.orderDetails: select orderdetai0_.orderId as orderId2_4_0_, orderdetai0_.id as id1_4_0_, orderdetai0_.id as id1_4_1_, orderdetai0_.orderId as orderId2_4_1_, orderdetai0_.price as price3_4_1_, orderdetai0_.productId as productI4_4_1_, orderdetai0_.quantity as quantity5_4_1_ from ordermapping orderdetai0_ where orderdetai0_.orderId=?
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:0> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CollectionQuerySpaceImpl@4938577d]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:1> -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.EntityQuerySpaceImpl@78c1ba9c]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG QuerySpacesImpl:174 - Adding QuerySpace : uid = <gen:1>-id -> org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.spaces.CompositeQuerySpaceImpl@36446098]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : myitemId
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : colorId
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : isActive
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG MetamodelGraphWalker:137 - Visiting attribute path : updatedDate
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG FetchStyleLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy:150 - Building LoadPlan...
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor:101 - processing queryspace <gen:0>
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG LoadPlanTreePrinter:55 - LoadPlan(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.SubCategory.myitemMapping)
    - Returns
       - CollectionReturnImpl(collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.SubCategory.myitemMapping, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.SubCategory.myitemMapping])
          - (collection element) CollectionFetchableElementEntityGraph(entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.myitemMapping, querySpaceUid=<gen:1>, path=[com.aaa.bbb.domain.SubCategory.myitemMapping].<elements>)
    - QuerySpaces
       - CollectionQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, collection=com.aaa.bbb.domain.SubCategory.myitemMapping)
          - SQL table alias mapping - myitemmapp0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {myitemId1_2_0_}
          - entity-element alias suffix - 1_
          - 1_entity-element suffixed key columns - myitemId1_2_1_, colorId2_2_1_
          - JOIN (JoinDefinedByMetadata(elements)) : <gen:0> -> <gen:1>
             - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:1>, entity=com.aaa.bbb.domain.myitemMapping)
                - SQL table alias mapping - myitemmapp0_
                - alias suffix - 1_
                - suffixed key columns - {myitemId1_2_1_, colorId2_2_1_}
                - JOIN (JoinDefinedByMetadata(id)) : <gen:1> -> <gen:1>-id
                   - CompositeQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:1>-id)
                      - SQL table alias mapping - myitemmapp0_

2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG CollectionLoader:83 - Static select for collection com.aaa.bbb.domain.SubCategory.myitemMapping: select myitemmapp0_.myitemId as myitemId1_2_0_, myitemmapp0_.colorId as colorId2_2_0_, myitemmapp0_.myitemId as myitemId1_2_1_, myitemmapp0_.colorId as colorId2_2_1_, myitemmapp0_.isActive as isActive3_2_1_, myitemmapp0_.updatedDate as updatedD4_2_1_ from myitemmapping myitemmapp0_ where myitemmapp0_.myitemId=? order by myitemmapp0_.myitemId, myitemmapp0_.colorId
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG SchemaManagementToolCoordinator:56 - No actions specified; doing nothing
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG JtaPlatformInitiator:42 - No JtaPlatform was specified, checking resolver
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG JtaPlatformResolverInitiator:33 - No JtaPlatformResolver was specified, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG StandardJtaPlatformResolver:102 - Could not resolve JtaPlatform, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG NamedQueryRepository:151 - Checking 0 named HQL queries
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG NamedQueryRepository:167 - Checking 0 named SQL queries
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG SessionFactoryRegistry:52 - Initializing SessionFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry@5f5d7aba
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG SessionFactoryRegistry:74 - Registering SessionFactory: 7a3fa62c-d42e-4987-b4e6-8fb5b8facaf9 (<unnamed>)
2018-09-25 18:28:52 DEBUG SessionFactoryRegistry:81 - Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.077 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@65ce574c] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.326 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/rest/*'], []
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.520 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init> Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@eda5c39, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4262a313, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5b64ac4f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3a319ec6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@6ed8bf4a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@f0036e3, com.aaa.bbb.config.CustomFilter@7a9ae2b4, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7a116569, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5d6901d9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@65467de2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2707ec80, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1d469374, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@577cbcc4]
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.670 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/default]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View com.aaa.bbb.controller.DefaultController.defaultAfterLogin(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.674 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/rest/greeting]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aaa.bbb.controller.HelloController.sayHello()
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.674 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/rest/test],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aaa.bbb.controller.HelloController.sayHelo()
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.676 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/LoginService/app],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.aaa.bbb.domain.Status com.aaa.bbb.controller.LoginController.login()
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.676 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/LoginService/logout],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.aaa.bbb.domain.Status com.aaa.bbb.controller.LoginController.logout()
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.677 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/MasterService/masterData/{lastUpdatedDate}]}" onto public com.aaa.bbb.domain.Status com.aaa.bbb.controller.MasterController.getMasterDatas(java.lang.String)
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.679 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/TransactionService/saveOrder/{lastUpdatedDate}],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.aaa.bbb.domain.Status com.aaa.bbb.controller.TransactionController.saveOrder(com.aaa.bbb.domain.PlaceOrderTransaction,java.lang.String)
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.679 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/TransactionService/purchaseOrder/{lastUpdatedDate}],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.aaa.bbb.domain.Status com.aaa.bbb.controller.TransactionController.purchaseOrder(com.aaa.bbb.domain.Order,java.lang.String)
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.681 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/user/home]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aaa.bbb.controller.UserController.home(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.681 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register Mapped "{[/user/error]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aaa.bbb.controller.UserController.error()
25-Sep-2018 18:28:53.789 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.162 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.inaaaontrollerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 25 18:28:47 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.487 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7431 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.520 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.522 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.524 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet': initialization started
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.547 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 23 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.560 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/bbb.war has finished in 10,970 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.561 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.740 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 179 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.740 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.756 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 16 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.756 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.771 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 15 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.771 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.794 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 22 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.794 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.821 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 27 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.830 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.843 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
25-Sep-2018 18:28:54.881 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 11375 ms
25-Sep-2018 18:29:02.033 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-6] javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
```

Comment: Tried posting the error in Google? Several posts in stackoverflow about that. Not tomcat or servlets related but springboot iirc

Comment: Which server is it? I guess weblogic, but which version? Also which concrete impl version do you use for JSF? Remember to tell all of this in every question you make, it's very difficult to guess the issue otherwise..

Comment: yeah i use java prime faces on a apache tomcat 8.0 with java 1.8 and jvm 1.8